# Actualizar npm en fedora

Tags: nodejs, react-native, npm, fedora

como puedo actualizar nmp  en fedora 28. Me sale este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1):

No sé si funcionará con Fedora pero siempre he actualizdo con la opción update.

```
npm update
```

O también puedes usar:

```
npm i -g npm
```

Espero que te ayude

Comment: No me funcionó, no hubo forma. Finalmente instalé Debian y todo funcionó bien.